# AWS-CDK cannot import core

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I have recently been asked to learn the AWS-CDK module in Python to handle deployments and following the examples on in the AWS-CDK documentation I am getting an error that indicates it cannot import 'core'

I have created a virtual environment that is using Python 3.6.6 and am running CDK version 1.16.2 (build 5893301) all running on a Windows 10 64-bit machine in VSCode

```py
from aws_cdk import core
```

I would expect this to just load the constructor but it just returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'core'
```

I have searched and searched and I cannot seem to find what I am doing wrong or anything that contradicts the documentation on the CDK site. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your current directory contain a file called `aws_cdk.py`?

Comment: Sometimes it's the simple things. There is a directory called aws_cdk that was created by the init because my parent directory was named aws-cdk the init created a directory called aws_cdk. The original directory wasn't an issue, but when it python-ed the project directory it replaced the dash with an underscore. Thanks @jordanm

Comment: This worked for me, probably should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Might be related to conda / venv interactions.

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt --user
```

Answer (score 1):

```
aws-cdk-lib==2.34.0
constructs>=10.0.0,<11.0.0
aws-cdk.aws-kinesisfirehose-alpha
aws_cdk.aws-kinesisfirehose-destinations-alpha
aws_cdk.core

pip list|grep core
```

Answer (score 0):

Is aws_cdk.core installed in your environment?
I have this:

```
pip list|grep core
aws-cdk.core                        1.68.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the cdk.json **"app" value** can also generate this error.
Example of the cdk.json file which used to generate the error:

```
{
  "app": "python3 app.py",
  "context": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Changing the app **value** from **python3** to **python** resolved the problem for me. Like this:

```
{
  "app": "python app.py",
  "context": {
    ...
  }
}
```

I am not entirely sure why this happens as I am using python 3.8 and I can see a python.exe in the python path/environment variables. If I deactivate the virtual env, and I have cdk installed globally, this problem goes away regardless of whether I use python or python3 for the app value. Therefore, I suspect it's got to do something with environment paths.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to load this module that means it is not installed. It is possible that it is not installed in the python virtual environment you are using. When I search aws_cdk module in my working directory using `find . -name aws_cdk` , I found that I had two virtual environments setup. One was under venv and other one was .venv. And the module installed were installed in one of them but not in the other environment. Switching the environment and installing the module fixed the error.